Is the androidx.security:security-crypto module being deprecated or not? What is the alternative?
Trawling through android documentation and I found information indicating that the jetpack security module androidx.security:security-crypto has been deprecated, here are some of the links https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/cryptography#jetpack_security_crypto_library
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2761067
However, I find that the security module is still being used and not a lot of information about alternatives. Also, I use the kotlin extension in my project androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx:1.1.0-alpha06 for EncryptedSharedPreferences and I do not see any deprecation warning. Is this library deprecated? What should I be using instead?

I believe that it depends on the library "com.google.crypto.tink", and it has been deprecated.

Seems so:
https://proandroiddev.com/securing-the-future-navigating-the-deprecation-of-encrypted-shared-preferences-91ce3c20ae8d
https://www.spght.dev/articles/04-06-2022/owasp-m2
https://x.com/Sp4ghettiCode/status/1786033489675944311
https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/cryptography#jetpack_security_crypto_library
Jetpack security crypto library is deprecated. This only affects cases where you have the following dependencies in your app module's build.gradle file:

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0"
}

No idea of a good alternative. This one has some weird crashes without any official explanation of how to deal with them in case they are expected to have them:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176215143

Perfect example by Google of library deprecation bad practices: 1. don't announce the deprecation in the official page (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security); 2. don't mention why it was deprecated; 3. don't provide guidance on migration options to move away from that library

@Diego It didn't even get to be widely known and have a relatively stable state that all people can use.

Hi, I am the original author of the top three links listed in the answer here
The source at the moment is the last link mentioned in the answer. We are still awaiting more confirmation, but it would seem JetSec Crypto is indeed deprecated

@EdHolloway-George the commit in the source code even suggests what to use instead:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/3724241aab8a48dbfd5cc147869350fd6511bb97%5E%21/
Basically they say "use SharedPreferences instead of EncryptedSharedPreferences; use File instead of EncryptedFile and KeyGenerator with AndroidKeyStore instead of MasterKey".

@EdHolloway-George How did you find my answer here? Also, why was it deprecated, and what can we use instead? Using SharedPreferences means it is less secure... Can't we have some good alternative?

@androiddeveloper , Diego is right. It's not because it is "not widely known" that writing and tagging the lib as deprecated/unmaintained on the very page of the lib... People as me just implemented the lib to find out months later that it is deprecated in a dark SO post...
